# Caused by: gherkin.parser.ParseError: Parse error Found scenario_outline when expecting one of: comment, row, tag. (Current getState: examples

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Caused by: gherkin.parser.ParseError: Parse error Found scenario_outline when expecting one of: comment, row, tag. (Current getState: examples

```
@config-cms-iwc-tests.yml @login

Feature: CMS IWC - Login Page

  @login-01
  Scenario Outline: Validate Login pop up.
    Given user navigate to iwc for <zone> in <language>
    When user clicks on Login link
    Then Login Popup should be displayed
    And Login popup heading should be displayed
  Examples:
 ## ${iwc-test.login}

  @login-02
  Scenario Outline:Validate Forgot Your Password Link
    Given user navigate to iwc for <zone> in <language>
    And user clicks on Login link
    #Then Login Popup should be displayed
    When user clicks on Forgot Your Password link
    Then Forgot Password popup should be displayed
    And Forgot Password popup heading should be displayed
    Examples:
 ## ${iwc-test.login}
```

Comment: What is `${iwc-test.login}` ? The parser expects tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

As @ou_ryperd mentioned the parser expects tabular data. You have to send the data in the examples table as shown below.

```
 Examples:
 |zone|language|
 |1   | lang1  |
 |2   | lang2  |
```